# Rendering differences with white-space: pre-wrap

Tags: html, css, webkit

I found some unexpected rendering in a web application I'm working on.  It's reproducible in Chrome and Opera, but not Firefox, Edge or Internet Explorer.  That suggests a Webkit link.

Anyway, here's the smallest reproduction I could find.

```css
div { white-space:pre-wrap; }
```

```html
<div style="width:10px; background:blue; ">                      </div>
<div style="width:2px;  background:green;">                      </div>
```

The unexpected thing about this is that in Chrome and Opera (on my machine) the green box is much taller than the blue box.

What is correct behavior in this case?  Should I file a bug for webkit?

For those that can't reproduce (like macOS) here's a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: look the same for me of all browsers on my MacBook. Safari 10 looks like chrome and firefox. you can screen shot?

Comment: At first glance it looks like WebKit is right; `pre-wrap` is supposed to preserve white space, and each space you've given is ~2px wide, so it's wrapping those to new lines.

Comment: @TylerH:  You're right that the spaces are wrapping, but that doesn't fully explain it.  Why doesn't the blue rectangle have some wrapped lines also?

Comment: Testing on Chrome, the issue is the width of the div. At 3px and less, both divs wrap. At 4px and up, neither div wraps. The question is, what's triggering the change at the 3-4 pixel mark?

Comment: @recursive I didn't think of that until after I had left the computer for the evening... oops! Still, some weird behavior here.